# Recursive Query using Temp Tables instead of CTE?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, common-table-expression, temp-tables, recursive-query

I'm migrating a query from Oracle to SQL Server. My query is using a CTE, and inside this CTE it have multiple recursive queries using CONNECT BY PRIOR which SQL Server don't have similar function. Below is what looks like in my ORACLE query:

```
WITH CTE1 --Oracle CTE here
(   
       SELECT FROM --derived table here
       (
             SELECT FROM TABLE CONNECT BY PRIOR --Oracle recursive function here
             UNION
             SELECT FROM TABLE --tables are joins to the recursive function above
        )
       CONNECT BY PRIOR --Oracle recursive function here
)
SELECT FROM CTE1 --query CTE table above
```

I had created a CTE recursive queries like below, but SQL Server CTE doesn't allow me to create "multiple" or "nested" recursive queries so that I can use them in just one query. So I would like to ask if its possible if we an also create recursive queries using Temp Table? Thank you very much.

```
WITH cte1 ( "PARENT ID", "PARENT NAME", "CHILD ID", "CHILD NAME" ) AS
(
    SELECT t1."PARENT ID", t1."PARENT NAME", t1."CHILD ID", t1."CHILD NAME", cteInner."LEVEL" + 1
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN ct1 cteInner
        ON t1."PARENT ID" = cteInner."CHILD ID"
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

Comment: A single query can have multiple CTEs. You can use recursion with standard tsql - but there is no direct equivalent functionality to that of a recursive CTE. And one piece of advice - do NOT develop the habit of using double quotes or names that do not adhere to rules for regular identifiers. At least don't do that without a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple CTEs by comma separating them after you've closed the bracket; you only need to write the `WITH` statement once at the top of the CTE section.

Along the lines of the below example:

```sql
WITH     
    cte1 AS ( *insert sql here* )    
,   cte2 AS ( SELECT * FROM cte1 )

SELECT * FROM cte2
```

Then you can write multiple CTEs in one query.